# Updating existing installation using java web start application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have been using Java web start for my application and I know accessing the application using web url will guaranteed the most recent version but I am curious to know if there is any way we can force the java web start application to automatically uninstall the existing version and update the application to the latest version while accessing through the shortcut.

Comment: It should update even when run through a desktop link. Can you post your JNLP configuration file? How are you initially installing the desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that. Since you are using the shortcut you are using the local downloaded copy of the JNLP file when starting javaws. You (or your users) will have to click on the 'start with webstart' link on the site to ensure that the newest JNLP is downloaded which can then include the update application jars.

We do not allow shortcuts for our JNLP webstart applications which means the users must always use the link on the webpage to start our application for this exact reason.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It's been a while since I used Web Start and I seem to remember it working; but more concretely, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/ states quite clearly that "Updates to a Java Web Start application are automatically downloaded when the application is run standalone from the user's desktop."

Comment: @JasonC I know I had trouble with this at work, and that starting an 'offline' from an existing JNLP did not download a new JNLP file even if it was available on the server. Maybe web-start has evolved since, I'll have to do some testing.

Comment: Updating the JNLP is harder than updating the archives referenced in it.  *"We do not allow shortcuts for our JNLP webstart applications"*  You can specify a preference for no shortcut, but cannot prevent the user creating one.  -- The situation you are talking about sounds more like a JNLP that is actively generated with different arguments or properties.  Not only does it **not** make sense to put a desktop shortcut, but the 'must click web link' also makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`javaws -uninstall`](http://download.java.net/jdk7u6/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) to remove all applications from the cache.

Or `javaws -uninstall <jnlp-file>` in order to remove a specific application.

Answer (score 0):

The application should update itself automatically. If you want to be sure only the new stuff is downloaded you can delete the cache (this sometimes help when there are problems). The location of cache under Windows 7 is usually at    `..user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\`